# How can I pass data between views via segue in a Xamarin.mac Cocoa app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.mac

I am developing a **Xamarin.Mac** **Cocoa** app in C# with *visual studio* for *Mac*.

I would like to pass an object from my first view controller to the next view controller. I have a segue called `LaunchSecondView` that starts the second view. And I need an object `class Person` from the first view in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to set a public property in your second view controller :

```
public Person MainPerson { get; set; }
```

You’ll need to override the method called `PrepareForSegue`. Inside it, you identify the destination controller (your second view), and in case you have multiple segues, it is a good practice to use a switch case statement.

```
public override void PrepareForSegue(NSStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);

    switch (segue.Identifier)
    {
        case "LaunchSecondView":
            {
                SecondViewClass target = segue.DestinationController as SecondViewClass;
                target.Person = CurrentPerson;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```